# Regex match also negative decimal numbers

Tags: java, regex

I have the following regex which I use to match/validate decimal numbers:

```
String[] inputs = {
    "0",
    "0.0",
    "0.1",
    "-0.1",
    "-0.123",
    "-123.123",
};
final String REG_PATTERN_VALID_DECIMAL_NUMBER = "((?<!\\S)\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?(?!\\S))|.";
for (String input : inputs) {
    boolean validInput = input.matches(REG_PATTERN_VALID_DECIMAL_NUMBER);
    System.out.println("input: " + input + " ; isValid: " + validInput);
}
```

The output is:

```
input: 0 ; isValid: true
input: 0.0 ; isValid: true
input: 0.1 ; isValid: true
input: -0.1 ; isValid: false
input: -0.123 ; isValid: false
input: -123.123 ; isValid: false
```

So all the positive numbers pass except negative numbers.
How can I extend my regular expression to accept also negative number, eg. accept first character "-" ?

Comment: Use `-?` which will match `-` zero times or once, effectively making the `-` optional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern doesn't have to be that complicated, try this:

```
^-?\d+(\.\d+)?$
```

`-?` is the part that matches both with and without the `-` sign. `?` means 1 or 0 occurrences.

Comment: What's the difference between `[0-9]\d*` and `\d+`?

Comment: @MauricePerry there's no difference here, but in my case I had `[1-9]` and `|0` in the end to make sure numbers like 0284 won't be matched, I'll fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need your existing regex to match positive/negative decimals. You just need to include an `-?` before your pattern, to match 1 or zero '-'.

```
final String REG_PATTERN_VALID_DECIMAL_NUMBER = "-?\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?";
```

Answer (score 1):

If you prepend an optional - character it should work:

```
final String REG_PATTERN_VALID_DECIMAL_NUMBER = "((?<!\\S)-?\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?(?!\\S))|.";
```